# How to avoid HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException with Spring SseEmitter on timeout

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, server-sent-events

I get the error `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` when the SseEmitter has timed out.

When searching in SO for this error code, I find only answers relating to registering a converter for the `ResponseBody`. But I can't see how this could be the same problem I am facing, since the content type is `text/event-stream` and is handled by Spring automatically.

However, the communication seems to flow good otherwise; the messages are being sent properly to the client.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/channel")
@CrossOrigin
public SseEmitter channel() throws IOException {

    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();

    // Storing the emitter
    // ...
    player.setEmitter(emitter);

    return emitter;
}
```

In the player, I do this:

```
public void setEmitter(SseEmitter emitter) {
    if (this.emitter != null) {
        // Old emitter must be completed for user
        this.emitter.complete();
    }

    this.emitter = emitter;
    this.emitter.onTimeout(() -> {
        if (this.emitter != null) this.emitter.complete();
    });
    this.emitter.onCompletion(() -> this.emitter = null);
}

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (this.emitter != null) {
        emitter.send(message);
    }
}
```

(By the way, is this a good way of handling the emitter; i.e. the registration of onTimeout and onCompletion? The idea is that a new emitter is created on every reconnect and that means the old one needs to be replaced.)

The messages sent are a data structure serialized into JSON text. On the JavaScript client it is correctly deserialized into a JSON object. I have not specified the JSON content anywhere, as I think from the SseEmitter/SSE perspective, it is just text.

During the time the connection is established, everything works fine. At every timeout, the client reconnects as it should.
However I seem to always get the following exception in connection to the timeout and reconnect procedure:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:191) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595) ~[jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:549) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:348) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:262) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:na]
```

I am using Spring Boot with Jetty. I also get this error, but I think it is a consequence of the first:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1243) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:567) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:544) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:167) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:167) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendError(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:257) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:121) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:137) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1185) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1022) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:549) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:348) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:262) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not on the server side. After clicking around on the client a couple of times, there were suddenly two client side EventSource objects. This is what caused the errors.

Comment: By the way this also occurs when you use spring boot with embedded tomcat server, specially when you break the connection of the event stream with the server by manually reloading the browser page. In your server side timeout handler you may be marking the stream as complete but still there is a dispatch made to the MVC which is not handled by default and results in this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs on servlet-based servers like jetty or tomcat, because the servlet api doesn't notify when a client connection is closed. The only way to find out if a connection has been closed is to send a message, and stop the sseemitter if a IOException is triggered.

The problem is that the IOException is also dispatched to spring mvc that fails to find a suitable httpmessageconverter, hence throwing a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.

The best option is to migrate the sse emitter to a netty-powered microservice. In my case, i had to stick to tomcat. Here is how i solved it in my spring boot application :

- I added a custom httpmessagecomverter to handle Map for media type text/event-stream
- I added an error handler using spring web `@ExceptionHandler` to mute ClientAbortException

Comment: But i've do some experiment, it seems that the ```HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException``` and ```AsyncRequestTimeoutException ``` will be thrown just after ```SseEmitter``` timeout, without the need to write message to a closed connection.